# How to fetch a data of a certain user using in codeigniter and edit is not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am a beginner can anyone give me some tips and suggestion how will i fetch some users data. I am creating a reservation and I want to happen is when the user login they can see they're history of reservaton that they can cancel or delete it. I just want to fetch only they're reservation info data  but what happen is it fetches all the data in the database and one more problem is my edit is not working and it doesn't any give's error and i try to put alternate my condition my if else statement what happens is the edit is working and the add is not. i am really confused what i am going to do

**historycont**

```
   <?php
  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class Historycont extends CI_Controller {


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('book_model');
    }


    public function index()
    {

    $data['occasion']=$this->book_model->get_all_books();
    $this->load->view('history',$data);
    }
    public function book_add()
    {
        $data = array(

                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'mobilenum' => $this->input->post('mobilenum'),
                'homeadd' => $this->input->post('homeadd'),
                'occasiontype' => $this->input->post('occasiontype'),
                'startdate' => $this->input->post('startdate'),
                'enddate' => $this->input->post('enddate'),
            );
        $insert = $this->book_model->book_add($data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }
    public function ajax_edit($id)
    {
        $data = $this->book_model->get_by_id($id);



        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    public function book_update()
    {
    $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'mobilenum' => $this->input->post('mobilenum'),
            'homeadd' => $this->input->post('homeadd'),
            'occasiontype' => $this->input->post('occasiontype'),
            'startdate' => $this->input->post('startdate'),
            'enddate' => $this->input->post('enddate'),
        );
    $this->book_model->book_update(array('id' => $this->input->post('id')), 
    $data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}

public function book_delete($id)
{
    $this->book_model->delete_by_id($id);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}



}
```

**history_model**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class history_model extends CI_Model
{

var $table = 'occasion';


public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}


public function get_all_books()
{
$this->db->from('occasion');
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}


public function get_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row();
}

public function book_add($data)
{
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}

public function book_update($where, $data)
{
    $this->db->update($this->table, $data, $where);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}

public function delete_by_id($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete($this->table);
}


}
```

**history_view**

```
    <div class= "col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">

    <h1>Profile Page</h1>

    HELLO, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>


    <br><br>

    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/auth/logout">Logout</a>


    <div class="container">
    <h1>History</h1>
    </center>
    <h3>Book List</h3>
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="add_book()"><i class="glyphicon 
    glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Book</button>
    <br />
    <br />
  <table id="table_id" class="table table-striped table-bordered" 
  cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Mobile Number</th>
                <th>Home Address</th>
                <th>Occasion Type</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>End Date</th>

      <th style="width:125px;">Action
      </p></th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
            <?php foreach($occasion as $book){?>
                 <tr>
                     <td><?php echo $book->id;?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $book->username;?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $book->mobilenum;?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $book->homeadd;?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $book->occasiontype;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $book->startdate;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $book->enddate;?></td>
                            <td>
     <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="edit_book(<?php echo $book->id;? 
     >)"> 
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" 
    onclick="delete_book(<?php echo $book->id;?>)"><i class="glyphicon 
    glyphicon-remove"></i></button>


  </td>
  </tr>
  <?php }?>



  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>MobileN umber</th>
      <th>Home Address</th>
      <th>Occasion Type</th>
      <th>Start Date</th>
      <th>End Date</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
      </tfoot>
      </table>

      </div>

     <script src="<?php echo base_url('assests/jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js')? 
     >"></script>
     <script src="<?php echo 
     base_url('assests/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')?>"></script>
     <script src="<?php echo 
     base_url('assests/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')?>"></script>
     <script src="<?php echo 
     base_url('assests/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js')?>"></script>


     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready( function () {
     $('#table_id').DataTable();
     } );
     var save_method; //for save method string
     var table;


  function add_book()
  {
  save_method = 'add';
  $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
  $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal
 //$('.modal-title').text('Add Person'); // Set Title to Bootstrap modal title
   }

   function edit_book(id)
   {
  save_method = 'update';
  $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals

  //Ajax Load data from ajax
  $.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo site_url('book/ajax_edit/')?>/" + id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {

        $('[name="id"]').val(data.id);
        $('[name="username"]').val(data.username);
        $('[name="mobilenum"]').val(data.mobilenum);
        $('[name="homeadd"]').val(data.homeadd);
        $('[name="occasiontype"]').val(data.occasiontype);
        $('[name="startdate"]').val(data.startdate);
        $('[name="enddate"]').val(data.enddate);


        $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
        $('.modal-title').text('Edit Book'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error get data from ajax');
    }
});
}



function save()
{
  var url;
  if(save_method == 'add')
  {

      url = "<?php echo site_url('book/book_add')?>";


  }
  else
  {
   var url;
    url = "<?php echo site_url('book/book_update')?>";
  }


   // ajax adding data to database
      $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {
           //if success close modal and reload ajax table
           $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
          location.reload();// for reload a page
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error adding / update data');
        }
    });
}

function delete_book(id)
{
  if(confirm('Are you sure delete this data?'))
  {
    // ajax delete data from database
      $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('book/book_delete')?>/"+id,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {

           location.reload();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error deleting data');
   }
  });

  }
  }

  </script>

  <!-- Bootstrap modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
   label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
   <h3 class="modal-title">Add Form</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body form">
   <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
   <input type="hidden" value="" name="book_id"/>
   <div class="form-body">
   <div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-3">Username</label>
   <div class="col-md-9">
   <input name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" 
   type="text">
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Mobile Number</label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
  <input name="mobilenum" placeholder="Mobilenum" class="form- 
  control" type="text">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Home Address</label>
 <div class="col-md-9">
<input name="homeadd" placeholder="Homeadd" 
 class="form-control" type="text">

 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3">Occasion Type</label>
 <div class="col-md-9">
 <input name="occasiontype" placeholder="Occasiontype" class="form- 
 control" type="text">
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3">Start Date</label>
 <div class="col-md-9">
 <input name="startdate" placeholder="Startdate" class="form- 
 control" type="text">
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3">End Date</label>
 <div class="col-md-9">
 <input name="enddate" placeholder="Enddate" 
 class="form-control" type="text">

 </div>
 </div>

 </div>
 </form>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn- 
 primary">Save</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data- 
 dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
 </div>
 </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
 </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
 </div><!-- /.modal -->
 <!-- End Bootstrap modal -->

 </body>
 </html>
```

**db structure**

```
               --
 -- Table structure for table `occasion`
 --

  CREATE TABLE `occasion` (
  `username` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `mobilenum` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `homeadd` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `occasiontype` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `startdate` date NOT NULL,
  `enddate` date NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

 --
-- Dumping data for table `occasion`
--

INSERT INTO `occasion` (`username`, `id`, `mobilenum`, `homeadd`, `occasiontype`, 
`startdate`, `enddate`) VALUES
('piolo', 22, 'dsada', 'adada', 'ML', '2018-10-18', '2018-11-10'),
('piolo', 23, 'dsadada', 'adada', 'ML', '2018-10-18', '2018-11-10'),
('piolos', 24, 'adad', 'adada', 'adad', '2018-11-14', '2018-11-17'),
('hgfhf', 25, 'hfghf', 'fhfh', 'hfhf', '2018-10-18', '2018-10-19'),
('piolo', 26, 'dsada', 'adada', 'ML', '2018-11-01', '2018-11-10');

 -- --------------------------------------------------------
 CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `gender` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `created_date` date NOT NULL,
 `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `activated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

 --
 -- Dumping data for table `users`
 --

 INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `gender`, 
  `created_date`, `phone`, `activated`) VALUES
   (1, 'Krypto', 'jhonjerico@yahoo.com', 'e2246479f2c24d13d8f134b329cbcd85', 
  'Female', '2018-08-04', 'fdsfs', 0),
  (34, 'abcd', 'johnhular282@yahoo.com', 
  '20eabe5d64b0e216796e834f52d61fd0b70332fc', 
 'Male', '0000-00-00', '9082079424', 1),
 (35, 'abcde', 'johnhular282333@yahoo.com', 'fcea920f7412b5da7be0cf42b8c93759', 
 'Male', '0000-00-00', '9082079424', 0),
  (39, 'piolo', 'hular17@gmail.com', 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', 'Male', 
 '0000-00-00', '9082079424', 1),
 (40, 'aaaaa', 'batotswak2@yahoo.com', 'd0970714757783e6cf17b26fb8e2298f', 
 'Male', 
 '2018-09-17', '9082079424', 0),
 (42, 'louie', 'andyreaasinas@yahoo.com', 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', 
 'Male', 
 '2018-10-22', '13213132131', 0),
 (43, 'louie', 'andyreaasinas32@yahoo.com', 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', 
 'Male', '2018-10-22', '13213132131', 0),
 (44, 'louie', 'andyreaasinas32@yahoo.com3', 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', 
 'Male', '2018-10-22', '13213132131', 0),
 (45, 'intsik_potawatomi@yahoo.com', 'ianpilyo66@yahoo.com', 
 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', 'Male', '2018-10-22', '13213132131', 0),
 (49, 'michael louie', 'christianhular@gmail.com', 
 'fcea920f7412b5da7be0cf42b8c93759', 
 'Male', '2018-10-24', '13213132131', 1);
```

Comment: Can you explain little more your question? Where do you store user data? Do you use database for it. If so you have to fetch information from the datatable by user id

Comment: Yep i use database for it. My friend told me that also, I can't understand the logic of it if i will fetch the information from it by user id , where will i put it in the profile.php in my controller. Want i want to happen is whenever they login , they will see all their history or so information of their reservation.

Comment: You should show your code. what did you do already for this purpose. What datatables you are using. What queries. And what doesn't work. We can help you resolve issues with your code

Comment: Oh okay okay boss thank youuu :) , i will show you my code

Comment: Show your code and db stracture.

Comment: I edited my post , here's all the code and db structure.

Comment: i think you didnt call view ($this->load->view('edituser',$data);) thats why that page is plain